# Can't boot up Fedora 37 on my primary storage ssd after removing Windows 10 from secondary storage HDD

Tags: linux, installation, fedora

I need to do some stuff on a Windows machine. So I install Windows 10 on a separate Storage HDD and run it. After fulfilling my need, I removed Windows 10 and planned to use that Storage for another purpose. But when I tried to run the fedora it throws this window...
[image]

- I can still do data and media stuff when I boot up any Live bootable os.
- I have not changed any grub or dev related stuff from fedora

I want to go to my previous state where I can boot my Primary SSD fedora on it booted. I don't need any extra storage so I removed the secondary derive already.